My Ubuntu is freezing using AMD Ryzen 8600G
I have a PC with the following specs:

CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 8600G
RAM: 32GB DDR5 4800MHz (2x16GB)
Motherboard: ASUS TUF Gaming B650M-Plus
PSU: Gigabyte 550W
Display: LG 240Hz monitor

My system frequently freezes, likely due to issues with the AMDGPU driver, but I haven't been able to resolve it. The problem occurs on both DP (DisplayPort) and HDMI connections.
What I've Tried
I've experimented with various kernel boot options in /etc/default/grub under GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT. Here’s what I tested:

amdgpu.dc=0 → Black screen on boot.
amdgpu.dpm=0 → Black screen on boot.
amdgpu.runpm=0 → Black screen on boot.
amdgpu.gpu_recovery=1 or 0 → Freezes persist; sometimes the system recovers, sometimes not.
amdgpu.noretry=0 → Freezes persist and stay frozen.
amdgpu.ppfeaturemask=X → Tried multiple values; no improvement.

The only option that stops the freezes is nomodeset, but this disables GPU acceleration, locks the display at 60Hz, and reduces performance. It’s not a viable long-term solution.
Drivers and Distro Attempts
I installed AMDGPU Pro drivers (both open and proprietary versions) and Mesa drivers, but the issue persisted.
I’ve reinstalled my Linux system multiple times across different distributions:

Zorin OS 17 (tried twice).
Zorin OS 16.
Linux Mint Cinnamon.
Ubuntu 24.04 (tried twice).
Freezes happen on all of them.

I tried using Wayland and Xorg, Ubuntu Desktop, Gnome Desktop, Gnome Classic, Cinnamon and DDE.
Windows Behavior
On Windows, I encountered similar issues, including HYPERVISOR_ERROR, frequent freezes, and black screens. However, uninstalling AMD software and using only the Windows Update GPU driver seems to have resolved the problem there.
Hardware Checks
I’ve ruled out hardware issues by running several tests:

CPU and GPU stress tests: No errors.
Memtest86 (3 passes): No issues found.
SSD and HDD tests: Passed with no problems.

When Freezes Occur
Most often when using Chromium-based software (e.g., VS Code, Vivaldi Browser, Postman).
Firefox can also cause freezes.
Sometimes the system freezes when idle, with no specific application running.
It is worth noting that entire system continues to work normally, SSH commands are OK and no other CPU issues.
Logs
Immediate log after one of freezes:
[drm:amdgpu_job_timedout [amdgpu]] *ERROR* ring gfx_0.0.0 timeout, signaled seq=122066, emitted seq=122068
2024-11-24T11:12:06.665580-03:00 isaac-Ubuntu kernel: [drm:amdgpu_job_timedout [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Process information: process vivaldi-bin pid 5600 thread vivaldi-bi:cs0 pid 5647
2024-11-24T11:12:06.665582-03:00 isaac-Ubuntu kernel: amdgpu 0000:0b:00.0: amdgpu: GPU reset begin!
2024-11-24T11:12:06.879538-03:00 isaac-Ubuntu kernel: amdgpu 0000:0b:00.0: [drm] REG_WAIT timeout 1us * 100000 tries - optc1_wait_for_state line:839
2024-11-24T11:12:07.301538-03:00 isaac-Ubuntu kernel: message repeated 2 times: [ amdgpu 0000:0b:00.0: [drm] REG_WAIT timeout 1us * 100000 tries - optc1_wait_for_state line:839]
2024-11-24T11:12:07.439538-03:00 isaac-Ubuntu kernel: [drm:mes_v11_0_submit_pkt_and_poll_completion.constprop.0 [amdgpu]] *ERROR* MES failed to response msg=3
2024-11-24T11:12:07.439551-03:00 isaac-Ubuntu kernel: [drm:amdgpu_mes_unmap_legacy_queue [amdgpu]] *ERROR* failed to unmap legacy queue
2024-11-24T11:12:07.567536-03:00 isaac-Ubuntu kernel: [drm:mes_v11_0_submit_pkt_and_poll_completion.constprop.0 [amdgpu]] *ERROR* MES failed to response msg=3
2024-11-24T11:12:07.567544-03:00 isaac-Ubuntu kernel: [drm:amdgpu_mes_unmap_legacy_queue [amdgpu]] *ERROR* failed to unmap legacy queue
2024-11-24T11:12:07.695534-03:00 isaac-Ubuntu kernel: [drm:mes_v11_0_submit_pkt_and_poll_completion.constprop.0 [amdgpu]] *ERROR* MES failed to response msg=3
2024-11-24T11:12:07.695538-03:00 isaac-Ubuntu kernel: [drm:amdgpu_mes_unmap_legacy_queue [amdgpu]] *ERROR* failed to unmap legacy queue
2024-11-24T11:12:07.824536-03:00 isaac-Ubuntu kernel: [drm:mes_v11_0_submit_pkt_and_poll_completion.constprop.0 [amdgpu]] *ERROR* MES failed to response msg=3
2024-11-24T11:12:07.824541-03:00 isaac-Ubuntu kernel: [drm:amdgpu_mes_unmap_legacy_queue [amdgpu]] *ERROR* failed to unmap legacy queue
2024-11-24T11:12:07.952539-03:00 isaac-Ubuntu kernel: [drm:mes_v11_0_submit_pkt_and_poll_completion.constprop.0 [amdgpu]] *ERROR* MES failed to response msg=3
2024-11-24T11:12:07.952548-03:00 isaac-Ubuntu kernel: [drm:amdgpu_mes_unmap_legacy_queue [amdgpu]] *ERROR* failed to unmap legacy queue
2024-11-24T11:12:08.080551-03:00 isaac-Ubuntu kernel: [drm:mes_v11_0_submit_pkt_and_poll_completion.constprop.0 [amdgpu]] *ERROR* MES failed to response msg=3
2024-11-24T11:12:08.080560-03:00 isaac-Ubuntu kernel: [drm:amdgpu_mes_unmap_legacy_queue [amdgpu]] *ERROR* failed to unmap legacy queue
2024-11-24T11:12:08.208541-03:00 isaac-Ubuntu kernel: [drm:mes_v11_0_submit_pkt_and_poll_completion.constprop.0 [amdgpu]] *ERROR* MES failed to response msg=3
2024-11-24T11:12:08.208546-03:00 isaac-Ubuntu kernel: [drm:amdgpu_mes_unmap_legacy_queue [amdgpu]] *ERROR* failed to unmap legacy queue
2024-11-24T11:12:08.337537-03:00 isaac-Ubuntu kernel: [drm:mes_v11_0_submit_pkt_and_poll_completion.constprop.0 [amdgpu]] *ERROR* MES failed to response msg=3
2024-11-24T11:12:08.337542-03:00 isaac-Ubuntu kernel: [drm:amdgpu_mes_unmap_legacy_queue [amdgpu]] *ERROR* failed to unmap legacy queue
2024-11-24T11:12:08.465537-03:00 isaac-Ubuntu kernel: [drm:mes_v11_0_submit_pkt_and_poll_completion.constprop.0 [amdgpu]] *ERROR* MES failed to response msg=3
2024-11-24T11:12:08.465542-03:00 isaac-Ubuntu kernel: [drm:amdgpu_mes_unmap_legacy_queue [amdgpu]] *ERROR* failed to unmap legacy queue
2024-11-24T11:12:08.669891-03:00 isaac-Ubuntu kernel: [drm:gfx_v11_0_cp_gfx_enable.isra.0 [amdgpu]] *ERROR* failed to halt cp gfx
2024-11-24T11:12:08.670530-03:00 isaac-Ubuntu kernel: amdgpu 0000:0b:00.0: amdgpu: MODE2 reset
2024-11-24T11:12:08.702533-03:00 isaac-Ubuntu kernel: amdgpu 0000:0b:00.0: amdgpu: GPU reset succeeded, trying to resume
2024-11-24T11:12:08.703530-03:00 isaac-Ubuntu kernel: [drm] PCIE GART of 512M enabled (table at 0x000000801FD00000).
2024-11-24T11:12:08.703534-03:00 isaac-Ubuntu kernel: amdgpu 0000:0b:00.0: amdgpu: SMU is resuming...
2024-11-24T11:12:08.705530-03:00 isaac-Ubuntu kernel: amdgpu 0000:0b:00.0: amdgpu: SMU is resumed successfully!
2024-11-24T11:12:08.707529-03:00 isaac-Ubuntu kernel: [drm] DMUB hardware initialized: version=0x08003700
2024-11-24T11:12:08.842521-03:00 isaac-Ubuntu kernel: [drm] kiq ring mec 3 pipe 1 q 0
2024-11-24T11:12:08.845519-03:00 isaac-Ubuntu kernel: [drm] VCN decode and encode initialized successfully(under DPG Mode).
2024-11-24T11:12:08.845521-03:00 isaac-Ubuntu kernel: amdgpu 0000:0b:00.0: [drm:jpeg_v4_0_hw_init [amdgpu]] JPEG decode initialized successfully.
2024-11-24T11:12:08.845522-03:00 isaac-Ubuntu kernel: amdgpu 0000:0b:00.0: amdgpu: ring gfx_0.0.0 uses VM inv eng 0 on hub 0
2024-11-24T11:12:08.845523-03:00 isaac-Ubuntu kernel: amdgpu 0000:0b:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.0.0 uses VM inv eng 1 on hub 0
2024-11-24T11:12:08.845523-03:00 isaac-Ubuntu kernel: amdgpu 0000:0b:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.1.0 uses VM inv eng 4 on hub 0
2024-11-24T11:12:08.845524-03:00 isaac-Ubuntu kernel: amdgpu 0000:0b:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.2.0 uses VM inv eng 6 on hub 0
2024-11-24T11:12:08.845525-03:00 isaac-Ubuntu kernel: amdgpu 0000:0b:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.3.0 uses VM inv eng 7 on hub 0
2024-11-24T11:12:08.845526-03:00 isaac-Ubuntu kernel: amdgpu 0000:0b:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.0.1 uses VM inv eng 8 on hub 0
2024-11-24T11:12:08.845526-03:00 isaac-Ubuntu kernel: amdgpu 0000:0b:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.1.1 uses VM inv eng 9 on hub 0
2024-11-24T11:12:08.845527-03:00 isaac-Ubuntu kernel: amdgpu 0000:0b:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.2.1 uses VM inv eng 10 on hub 0
2024-11-24T11:12:08.845527-03:00 isaac-Ubuntu kernel: amdgpu 0000:0b:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.3.1 uses VM inv eng 11 on hub 0
2024-11-24T11:12:08.845527-03:00 isaac-Ubuntu kernel: amdgpu 0000:0b:00.0: amdgpu: ring sdma0 uses VM inv eng 12 on hub 0
2024-11-24T11:12:08.845527-03:00 isaac-Ubuntu kernel: amdgpu 0000:0b:00.0: amdgpu: ring vcn_unified_0 uses VM inv eng 0 on hub 8
2024-11-24T11:12:08.845528-03:00 isaac-Ubuntu kernel: amdgpu 0000:0b:00.0: amdgpu: ring jpeg_dec uses VM inv eng 1 on hub 8
2024-11-24T11:12:08.845528-03:00 isaac-Ubuntu kernel: amdgpu 0000:0b:00.0: amdgpu: ring mes_kiq_3.1.0 uses VM inv eng 13 on hub 0
2024-11-24T11:12:08.846511-03:00 isaac-Ubuntu kernel: amdgpu 0000:0b:00.0: amdgpu: recover vram bo from shadow start
2024-11-24T11:12:08.846512-03:00 isaac-Ubuntu kernel: amdgpu 0000:0b:00.0: amdgpu: recover vram bo from shadow done
2024-11-24T11:12:08.846513-03:00 isaac-Ubuntu kernel: amdgpu 0000:0b:00.0: amdgpu: GPU reset(4) succeeded!
2024-11-24T11:12:08.847831-03:00 isaac-Ubuntu vivaldi-stable.desktop[5505]: amdgpu: amdgpu_cs_query_fence_status failed.
2024-11-24T11:12:08.922246-03:00 isaac-Ubuntu gnome-shell[5529]: amdgpu: The CS has been rejected (-125).
2024-11-24T11:12:08.922289-03:00 isaac-Ubuntu gnome-shell[5529]: (EE)
2024-11-24T11:12:08.922310-03:00 isaac-Ubuntu gnome-shell[5529]: (EE) Backtrace:
2024-11-24T11:12:08.922326-03:00 isaac-Ubuntu gnome-shell[5529]: (EE) 0: /usr/bin/Xwayland (0x5939722f8000+0x170222) [0x593972468222]
2024-11-24T11:12:08.922343-03:00 isaac-Ubuntu gnome-shell[5529]: (EE) 1: /usr/bin/Xwayland (0x5939722f8000+0x173016) [0x59397246b016]
2024-11-24T11:12:08.922360-03:00 isaac-Ubuntu gnome-shell[5529]: (EE) 2: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x7c4c5fa00000+0x45320) [0x7c4c5fa45320]
2024-11-24T11:12:08.922376-03:00 isaac-Ubuntu gnome-shell[5529]: (EE) 3: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (pthread_kill+0x11c) [0x7c4c5fa9eb1c]
2024-11-24T11:12:08.922392-03:00 isaac-Ubuntu gnome-shell[5529]: (EE) 4: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (gsignal+0x1e) [0x7c4c5fa4526e]
2024-11-24T11:12:08.922408-03:00 isaac-Ubuntu gnome-shell[5529]: (EE) 5: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (abort+0xdf) [0x7c4c5fa288ff]
2024-11-24T11:12:08.922426-03:00 isaac-Ubuntu gnome-shell[5529]: (EE) 6: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/radeonsi_dri.so (0x7c4c48a00000+0x955110) [0x7c4c49355110]
2024-11-24T11:12:08.922442-03:00 isaac-Ubuntu gnome-shell[5529]: (EE) 7: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/radeonsi_dri.so (0x7c4c48a00000+0x957bf6) [0x7c4c49357bf6]
2024-11-24T11:12:08.922458-03:00 isaac-Ubuntu gnome-shell[5529]: (EE) 8: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/radeonsi_dri.so (0x7c4c48a00000+0xfcb81) [0x7c4c48afcb81]
2024-11-24T11:12:08.922474-03:00 isaac-Ubuntu gnome-shell[5529]: (EE) 9: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/radeonsi_dri.so (0x7c4c48a00000+0x11d6fc) [0x7c4c48b1d6fc]
2024-11-24T11:12:08.922490-03:00 isaac-Ubuntu gnome-shell[5529]: (EE) 10: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x7c4c5fa00000+0x9ca94) [0x7c4c5fa9ca94]
2024-11-24T11:12:08.922510-03:00 isaac-Ubuntu gnome-shell[5529]: (EE) 11: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x7c4c5fa00000+0x129c3c) [0x7c4c5fb29c3c]
2024-11-24T11:12:08.922528-03:00 isaac-Ubuntu gnome-shell[5529]: (EE)
2024-11-24T11:12:08.922541-03:00 isaac-Ubuntu gnome-shell[5529]: (EE)
2024-11-24T11:12:08.922554-03:00 isaac-Ubuntu gnome-shell[5529]: Fatal server error:
2024-11-24T11:12:08.922567-03:00 isaac-Ubuntu gnome-shell[5529]: (EE) Caught signal 6 (Aborted). Server aborting
2024-11-24T11:12:08.922581-03:00 isaac-Ubuntu gnome-shell[5529]: (EE)
2024-11-24T11:12:08.922705-03:00 isaac-Ubuntu systemd[1]: Started systemd-timedated.service - Time & Date Service.
2024-11-24T11:12:08.922870-03:00 isaac-Ubuntu dbus-daemon[1031]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.timedate1'
2024-11-24T11:12:08.973725-03:00 isaac-Ubuntu systemd[1]: update-notifier-download.service: Deactivated successfully.
2024-11-24T11:12:08.973939-03:00 isaac-Ubuntu systemd[1]: Finished update-notifier-download.service - Download data for packages that failed at package install time.
2024-11-24T11:12:10.037516-03:00 isaac-Ubuntu vivaldi-stable.desktop[5505]: X connection to :0 broken (explicit kill or server shutdown).
2024-11-24T11:12:10.037714-03:00 isaac-Ubuntu gnome-shell[2707]: Connection to xwayland lost
2024-11-24T11:12:10.040499-03:00 isaac-Ubuntu gnome-shell[2707]: X Wayland crashed; attempting to recover
2024-11-24T11:12:10.041450-03:00 isaac-Ubuntu systemd[2414]: Stopped target gnome-session-x11-services-ready.target - GNOME session X11 services.
2024-11-24T11:12:10.041567-03:00 isaac-Ubuntu systemd[2414]: launchpadlib-cache-clean.service - Clean up old files in the Launchpadlib cache was skipped because of an unmet condition check (ConditionPathExists=/home/isaac/.launchpadlib/api.launchpad.net/cache).
2024-11-24T11:12:10.041615-03:00 isaac-Ubuntu systemd[2414]: Stopping org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.XSettings.service - GNOME XSettings service...
2024-11-24T11:12:10.042095-03:00 isaac-Ubuntu gnome-shell[2707]: Window manager warning: META_CURRENT_TIME used to choose focus window; focus window may not be correct.
2024-11-24T11:12:10.045563-03:00 isaac-Ubuntu systemd[2414]: org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.XSettings.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
2024-11-24T11:12:10.046175-03:00 isaac-Ubuntu gnome-shell[2707]: Using public X11 display :0, (using :1 for managed services)
2024-11-24T11:12:10.066368-03:00 isaac-Ubuntu systemd[2414]: org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.XSettings.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
2024-11-24T11:12:10.066531-03:00 isaac-Ubuntu systemd[2414]: Stopped org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.XSettings.service - GNOME XSettings service.
2024-11-24T11:12:10.066602-03:00 isaac-Ubuntu systemd[2414]: Stopped target gnome-session-x11-services.target - GNOME session X11 services.
2024-11-24T11:12:10.139094-03:00 isaac-Ubuntu systemd[2414]: app-gnome-vivaldi\x2dstable-5498.scope: Consumed 1min 28.870s CPU time.

I’m looking for a solution to make my PC stable on Linux with proper GPU acceleration. Any help is appreciated!

Does the freeze occur in Windows (not the HyperVisor)?  What happens if you stress test the card in software like 3DMark

For a long time I was having a problem with the video driver in Windows that would freeze the screen and then restart after a few seconds, and an AMD Adrenaline software reporting error screen would appear. After many installs, uninstalls and updates, this problem stopped. I tried to stress the GPU and nothing happened. I tried to play hours and hours of games and I had no screen freezes. But when I use the browser or Vscode... It freezes!
